# PHP Dependency Injection resolving class with primitive dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, primitive-types

I think I'm doing something wrong when trying to write my own Dependency Injection Container. I'm looking at the laravel's one, and it states in a comment

> ```
> // If the class is null, it means the dependency is a string or some other
> // primitive type which we can not resolve since it is not a class and
> // we will just bomb out with an error since we have no-where to go.
> ```

And the code for resolving the class dependencies:

```
protected function resolveDependencies(array $dependencies)
{
    $results = [];

    foreach ($dependencies as $dependency) {
        // If the dependency has an override for this particular build we will use
        // that instead as the value. Otherwise, we will continue with this run
        // of resolutions and let reflection attempt to determine the result.
        if ($this->hasParameterOverride($dependency)) {
            $results[] = $this->getParameterOverride($dependency);

            continue;
        }

        // If the class is null, it means the dependency is a string or some other
        // primitive type which we can not resolve since it is not a class and
        // we will just bomb out with an error since we have no-where to go.
        $result = is_null(Util::getParameterClassName($dependency))
                        ? $this->resolvePrimitive($dependency)
                        : $this->resolveClass($dependency);

        if ($dependency->isVariadic()) {
            $results = array_merge($results, $result);
        } else {
            $results[] = $result;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

This is my implementation of a such class: [Link to the code](https://pastebin.com/B0nJHqwT)

So I have the following questions:

1. What should I do If I have primitive types in my constructor? For example:
   `public function __construct(ServerConfig $config, RequestInterface $request)`
   But here `$request` is actually a `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` that has the following dependecies:

`public function __construct(string $method, $uri, array $headers = [], $body = null, string $version = '1.1') {}`

2. Should I DI classes that have no primitive types?
3. What happens if I have a class A, that Needs class B as DI, but Class B is dependant on class C, that has some primitive types?

Comment: How can this be related to Laravel as Laravel already has a container?